# Is here the punctuation use correct?

Tags: punctuation

[image]

It intends to say , 'hence, spring force will increase'.Is it a wrong way?There should be an oxford comma as ' ,and the system will '.Shouldn't there be?

Comment: Could you write the entire phrase the way you think it should be, and then point out what is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence seems to be missing a bunch of articles (for some reason)

> due to acquired velocity it will keep moving to *the* right and elongation in *the* spring will increase, hence, the spring force and the system will start decelerating *until* both masses come to rest.

An Oxford comma is not necessary since the spring and the mass are linked together.
The same as

> bacon and eggs

Comment: The write may get confused as , 'the spring force and the system will start decelerating' but it intends to  say only the system will decelerate and the spring force will increase with increase in its elongation.

Comment: Using "both" implies the spring and the system, if you only mean the system "will come to rest" then it needs to be reworded.